# What does utils.generateToken(64) do?

Tags: node.js

`var token = utils.generateToken(64);`

I have a vague idea what [it might be for](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-remember-me) but I wanted to know specifically just to be sure.

I didn't find anything in what's supposed to be the [official doc](https://github.com/graczykr/utils_node)

Answer (score 0):

That function will generate a unique id for you, the function can written like this:

[Reference here](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/session.js#L205)

```
var uid = require('uid2');

function generateToken(number) {
   return uid(number);
}
```

you need package `uid2` to run that function

```
npm install uid2
```

Read here to know how it work:

https://github.com/coreh/uid2/blob/master/index.js